# Copy single line from JUnit failure trace

Tags: eclipse, junit, copy, line, trace

Is there a way to copy a single line on a JUnit failure trace in Eclipse?

I want to able select and copy just the second line here for example:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by clicking the console-icon (see arrow pic) the stack trace is shown in the console-view. There you can select and copy whatever you want...

[image: console]

Comment: thanks that'll save a few steps, still wish there was a way to copy directly from this view so to have fewer clicks